# Flutter web does "hot restart" instead of "hot reload". Is "hot reload" supported on flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, hot-reload

I have used flutter_web for a while now and never really questioned that it always restarted the whole application when pressing "hot reload" but since now flutter_web got merged to the main flutter channel I´m wondering if I might do something wrong or if it's just not possible.

I am using the newest version of flutter (Channel dev, v1.10.14) and Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.70) and run the app in debug mode.

If this is unusual please tell me and i will upload my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As [per the FAQ of Flutter web](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web#does-hot-reload-work-with-a-web-app) hot reload is not supported yet. So we have to wait for some more time.

Answer (score 10):

It is [not supported](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/faq#does-hot-reload-work-with-a-web-app) yet.  [the issue here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041) to help them prioritize it!

Comment: I just added a comment on the page (now in 2023) to ask if there are any new developments on this. The web framework isn't the same as that of mobile apps, so it is a whole new beast when it comes to adding this feature. I still have high hopes that this is in the running for early 2023.

Answer (score 3):

It is 2023 and [this is still not supported](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041).

From that issue, seems like the team won't prioritize this problem, but will be focusing on WASM this year. Maybe we will get hot reload as a side effect of that (Blazor has it), but who knows.

And even though one could develop using desktop (that has hot reload), someone said in the issue that when the project grows it becomes a problem.

If hot reload on web is a must for you (it is for me), be careful choosing Flutter at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's April 2023, hot reload does not work on web so don't waste your time. below is the link of hot reload.
**https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload**

> **What is the difference between hot reload, hot restart, and full restart?**
>
> **1. **Hot reload**** loads code changes into the VM and re-builds
> the widget tree, preserving the app state; it doesn’t rerun main() or
> initState(). (⌘\ in Intellij and Android Studio, ⌃F5 in VSCode)
>
> **2.Hot restart** loads code changes into the VM, and restarts the
> Flutter app, losing the app state. (⇧⌘\ in IntelliJ and Android
> Studio, ⇧⌘F5 in VSCode)
>
> **3.Full restart** restarts the iOS, Android, or web app. This takes
> longer because it also recompiles the Java / Kotlin / ObjC / Swift
> code. On the web, it also restarts the Dart Development Compiler.
> There is no specific keyboard shortcut for this; you need to stop and
> start the run configuration.
>
> **Flutter web currently supports hot restart but not hot reload.**

Answer (score 1):

April 2023,

If the libraries you use are compatible, it may be advantageous to develop with Flutter Desktop instead of running flutter web on Chrome browser in the early stages of development.  Hot reload is supported in Flutter Desktop. This is by no means a perfect solution, but you can imagine how much more convenient web development would be if Flutter Web also supported hot reload.